# In c++ getline() is not reading all the letters of the string while accepting multiple strings one after the other

Tags: c++, string, getline

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t; //Number of test cases
    while(t--){
        cin.ignore();
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
2
AMbuj verma
Aaaa bBBB
Bm Chetan
```

Output:

```
AMbuj verma
aaa bBBB
m Chetan
```

The above program is not reading first character of the strings.

This is the output that I'm getting.

I have also used `cin.ignore()`

Comment: That's the reason: you ignore the first character of each line

Comment: Don't #include <bits/stdc++.h>, it's a private non standard header not meant to include.

Comment: Thank you!!My code is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is bring the `cin.ignore()` outside of your `while` loop since every time your loop works, it takes the first letter of your string.

```
    cin>>t; //Number of test cases
    cin.ignore();
    while(t--){

        string s,a;
        getline(cin,s);
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
```

Lastly why are you writing `string s, a` when there is no use of `string a` in your code.

Comment: Thank you!!My code got accepted.I've removed string a.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `cin.ignore();` in the loop so it will ignore one character in every iteration.  Since you only use `operator >>` once you need to move the call to `ignore` out of the loop and have it just after the input.

```
cin>>t; //Number of test cases
cin.ignore(); // get rid of newline
while(t--){
    string s,a;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!I moved cin.ignore() outside the loop and I'm getting the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes the `cin.ignore()` consumes your characters. Now to add something in detail the input is basically stored in buffer (not in case of redirection). Now when you use getline it does this.

```
(1) istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
(2) istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);<--you used this
```

> Extracts characters from `is` and stores them into `str` [getline(cin.str)]until the
>   delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n',
>   for (2)).
>
> The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in is or if
>   some other error occurs during the input operation.
>
> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded (i.e. it is
>   not stored and the next input operation will begin after it).

So when basically that `\n` is consumed and discarded by `getline` itself. Now you use `cin.ignore()`

> istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF); Extract and
>   discard characters Extracts characters from the input sequence and
>   discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one
>   compares equal to delim.

So you didn't specify anything-- so it discards one character that is available in buffer which is the first character. (But you thought there would  be the `\n` which will be consumed but it was not there as it was discarded by `getline()`.

That's how you get the output like this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!!